# to withdraw , to be withdrawn

Tags: grammar

I've read a definition for the word **withdraw** at Cambridge Dictionary and there was examples for it's usage.

Ex:The president has ordered troops **to be withdrawn** from the area.

but, I can't under stand why should I use the passive form **to be withdrawn** instead of the active form **to withdraw** , as long as the troops will do the action by themselves.

Thanks,

Comment: So, how would you write that sentence?

Comment: The president has ordered troops to withdraw from the area.

Comment: Oh, he spoke to them directly?

Comment: So, it came in the passive form because the President ordered the troops across their commander , not ordering them directly.
Is it the reason?

Comment: I guess the reason why **to withdraw** won't work is because an object should follow it, "*The president has ordered troops to withdraw **whom?** from the area*" whilst **to be withdrawn** means they themselves should be withdrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The president has ordered troops to be withdrawn from the area.

Withdrawing troops from an area is a long and complex process requiring planning, scheduling, coordination, etc.  The troops will not be simply turning around and going back by themselves in response to an order reality, but rather waiting for coordinated and planned orders (which may not occur to all at once) to do so.  Passive voice is appropriate here because of that.

The writer has chosen to abstract this involved process in a "personal" process for conciseness (*the troops be withdrawn* versus something like *that a process of orderly withdrawal be started*) and assumed you will follow along with that.